# Why launching more than 2 AVDs works only under specific conditions

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I came across weird problem that I dont fully understand. I try to start more than 2 AVD from terminal. It works even for 4 AVDs but only on special conditions.

There is a code I use for 3 AVDs:

```
echo "no" | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android create avd --name "Test-Emulator-API23-Nexus-5" --target "Google Inc.:Google APIs:23" --abi google_apis/x86_64  --device "Nexus 5" --skin "1080x1920"
echo "no" | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android create avd --name "Test-Emulator-API23-Nexus-7" --target "Google Inc.:Google APIs:23" --abi google_apis/x86_64  --device "Nexus 7" --skin "1200x1920"
echo "no" | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android create avd --name "Test-Emulator-API23-Nexus-10" --target "Google Inc.:Google APIs:23" --abi google_apis/x86_64  --device "Nexus 10" --skin "2560x1600"

$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb kill-server
$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb start-server

$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator -port 5556 -avd Test-Emulator-API23-Nexus-5  -gpu on &>/dev/null &
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator -port 5558 -avd Test-Emulator-API23-Nexus-7  -gpu on &>/dev/null &
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator -port 5560 -avd Test-Emulator-API23-Nexus-10  -gpu on &>/dev/null &
```

It works when I copy paste last 3 lanes which launches AVD to terminal AT ONCE. Then all 3 AVDs start at the same time and successfully launch. It also works for 4 AVDs.

It won't allow me to launch more than 2 AVDs if I try to do it sequentially. So I put 1st launch lane for Nexus-5. I wait until it boots completely. Then I put 2nd launch lane for Nexus-7 - it also boots successfully. And then if I try to launch more AVD I get freeze - black screen freeze on startup.

Any idea why this happens? Why can I launch many AVDs at the same time, but I can't start them one by one?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure about dual behavior, but to my knowledge, AVD occupies too much of RAM and may be thats the reason why launching more AVDs leaves no RAM space for further AVD

Comment: But if that was a case I could not have 4 AVDs working at the same time - but I have (so there are enough resources for them). Problem is only with the way I try to launch them.

Comment: Strange but interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is related to memory allowance set to HAXM. My HAXM RAM usage by default was 2gb. After reinstalling HAXM

> https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

and assigning 6gb of memory to it, I am able to start 4 AVDs in sequence.

My guess why it worked before was: because all AVDs were started at once - in the same moment, all of them passed memory limit check and because of that they were allowed to run.