# Does not open more than 2 emulators simultaneously

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

The IDE does not let me open more than 2 AVD simultaneously. After 2 are already running and attempting to start 3rd AVD - Android Studio displays the message **"Starting AVD"**, but when loading ends nothing happens. No logs, no errors.

If, for example, you choose to close one of already running AVD, and start another - it starts properly, *i.e. all AVDs behave well individually*.

If matters, I use:

- Nexus 6 API 23 (Android 6.0 Google APIs), x86;
- Nexus S API 22 (Android 5.1 Google APIs), x86;
- Pixel API 25 (Android 7.1.1 Google APIs), x86;
- Android Studio 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Have same problem today and found it related to RAM usage limit for HAXM

Found answer at here

> [Why launching more than 2 AVDs works only under specific conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606325/why-launching-more-than-2-avds-works-only-under-specific-conditions?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Reinstall HAXM and set more ram to fit your need

> https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

[image: Image: Set ram usage during HAXM installation]